# Alternative proof of infinitude of prime.

Tags: number-theory, alternative-proof

I was chatting with my friends and one of them asked if the difference between 2 consecutive primes is increasing with increasing in natural numbers,, then will we have a point where all primes get finished?? i.e. will there exist another prime number so far from where we are??

I had no answers of his question at that moment.

But then I thought about this question and tried to prove that primes will never get finished or primes are infinte

**My work**:

Suppose there are finite number of primes and let $q$ is a number which is the product of all primes.

But $q+1$ is always co-prime with $q$ .

Hence no factors of $q$ will divide $q+1$.

So, we will get another prime number and the process will continue till infinity.

So we have proved that  primes numbers are infinite.

I want to just verify that whether my prove is right or wrong.How can we prove it alternatively?

Comment: Yes, the prove is correct. You can just mention that $q+1$ is divisible by a prime number which is not in the "original" list.

Comment: Your proof is the same as Euclid's proof, the most classical one.

Comment: Implicit assumption::every natural number $n>1$ has a prime divisor. This also has to be proved.

Comment: Think of any big number and there are consecutive prime numbers with their difference greater than the number you thought of.

Comment: @jnyan: If you meant to say that for every number $n$, there is a sequence of consecutive **non-primes**, whose length is larger than $n$, then this doesn't prove that there is another prime number at the end of that sequence.

Comment: I was chatting with my friends and one of them asked if the difference
between 2 consecutive primes is increasing with increasing in natural
 numbers

::

While it is true that the difference between 2 consecutive primes *generally* increases it's not true that the difference between 2 consecutive primes is increasing. For instance $ 1706595 
\cdot 2^{11235} 
±  1$ are both prime. It's conjectured that there are infinite primes $p$ such that $p$ and $p+2$ are both prime.

Comment: It doesn't. But I was just referring to what op's friend said in the beginning of the question.

Comment: I know that OP has shown something which has been already shown but there is no reason to downvote the question. Downvotes are given to those questions which are written extreamly poorly or shows no effort. +1 by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got two questions here:

> 1. Is my proof correct??
> 2. How can we prove it  alternatively?

I have got answer for both.

$1$. Yes your proof is correct, though it shows a little deviation from the ancient Euclid's proof. For full proof [go there](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi96-W00enQAhUIsY8KHajMDvwQFggiMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprimes.utm.edu%2Fnotes%2Fproofs%2Finfinite%2Feuclids.html&usg=AFQjCNEk8qld7BO4d9K7t1BViKpYtg8yGg&sig2=mBwTx6n-kiz_XnIdoBNu3Q).

$2$. **Alternative Proof**: I think this is the easiest one after Euclid's great proof.

Suppose there is an integer $Q_n=n!+1$.

Suppose that the largest prime which divides $Q_n$ is $p$.

Assume that $p\le n$. Then $p|n!$ annd we also had assumed that $p$ is the largest prime which divide $Q_n$ so $p|Q_n\implies p|n!+1$ This gives us $p|1$. Which is not possible. So, $p\ge n$.

Now, suppose that there is a largest prime $q$. But, by the previous proof we know that there is a prime larger than $q$ which divides $q!+1$, which means $q$ is not the largest prime $\implies$ A contradiction. Hence, Number of primes are infinite.

You can get some more proves [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiO4v2zje3QAhXMRY8KHQKkBf4QFgggMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprimes.utm.edu%2Fnotes%2Fproofs%2Finfinite%2F&usg=AFQjCNF8AQhz4GXcpLWoxU7zDTE-fI6aBg&sig2=dYnxjXUQiWtX7SInK1T1vg&bvm=bv.141320020,d.c2I).

Comment: Euclid's exposition, in the language of sets, is that every finite set of primes omits a prime. I wonder if the Greeks thought about infinite sets...